# "Path bounds exceeded" while doing a Pex unit test

Tags: pex

I am trying to generate a Pex unit test on an example program. I created a webpage with `Default.aspx`. Now I opened the `default.aspx.cs` file and added the below given code to the code behind:

```
public int Add(int n1,int n2)
{
return n1+n2;
}
public int Subtract(int n1,int n2)
{
return n1-n2;
}
```

Now I right clicked inside the `default.aspx.cs` file, clicked "Run Pex". In the Pex exploration results I am getting a message "Path bounds exceeded".

I don't understand – what does this mean and what should I do to get my unit test to pass?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Test project first, then mark the methods with `[PexMethod]` etc.
Please follow this [guide from Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesaspnet.pdf) on testing ASP.NET with Pex and Moles.